# Cannot override startElement method

Tags: android, overriding

My class extends DefaultHandler.
It overrided 3 methods startDocument, EndDocument, EndElement successfully, but when i override StartElement, Eclipse show this error

> The method startElement(String, String, String, Attributes) of type SubscriptionHandler must override a superclass method

```
public void startElement (String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException  
{
//code
}
```

Please explain this for me. Thanks so much.

Comment: What's the import statement for `Attributes`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you imported the right `Attributes` class? You would see this error if you'd imported any `Attributes` class other than `org.xml.sax.Attributes`.

Comment: Oh thanks u. I just use Ctrl-Shift-O and Eclipse imported other Attributes, not org.xml.sax.Attributes.